# Refresh Google Maps API route

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a code:

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   zoom:6,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 });

 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


 var request = {
   origin: '<?= $_GET['from']; ?>', 
   destination: '<?= $_GET['to']; ?>',
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };

 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  route=Math.round(parseFloat(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value)*0.002);
   }
 });
```

I need to make Google Maps refresh the route when I enter new origin and destination in two inputs I'm thinking something about:

```
function renewMap() {
loc=$('input[name=location]').val();
des=$('input[name=destination]').val();

 var request = {
   origin: loc, 
   destination: des,
   travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
 };

 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  route=Math.round(parseFloat(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value)*0.002);
   }
 });
}
```

But obviously this doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting `loc` and `des` values??

Comment: firstly read deeply into the text :)
loc=$('input[name=location]').val();
des=$('input[name=destination]').val();

Comment: I can see that, my question is, are you getting values in `loc` and `dec` variables? did you tried alerting or consoling it?

Comment: yes, I get new values in loc and des variables. Everything is OK with those variables, just script doesn't refresh the route somewhy :)

Comment: What about the `status` being returned by your `directionsService.route` api call? Is it really `OK`?  There are many possible return values but you're only testing for OK. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#StatusCodes for all Status codes

Answer (score 1):

You are missing,

```
   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

in your second function `renewMap()`, may be because of this it is not updating